# jQuery: Call a function

Tags: jquery, function, call

I have a button with a jquery code that clears all data from a from.

```
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

The jQuery code looks something like this:

```
$("#reset").click(function()
{
    $(':input').val('');
...LOTS and lots of more code...
    $("#id").focus();
});
```

ALSO, separete from button...I have an ajax/php, where if successful, I want it to call the $("#reset").click() function. 
-I do not want to copy and paste the code.

How can I call that function?

This did not work:

```
$("#reset").click();
```

Here is a "dummy sample" of my ajax, just show what I want to do:

```
//AJAX
//#new
$("#add").click(function()
{
   //START:$.post
   $.post( "ajax.php" ,
      {...var...},

      function(msg)
      {
      if( msg == 1 )
      { //Successful

      ...code...
      $("#reset").click();
      ...more code...

      } //end: if
      else
      { ...else code...} //end: if.else
      }//end: $.post.function
   ); //END:$.post
}); //END:ajax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger an event:

```
$('#reset').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling $('#reset').click(); "should" work. Are you calling the click before attaching the click event handler? Or maybe you are attaching the event handler to the element before it exists on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling `click()` should work. If not, then look at [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

On a more general note - why would you not use form's standard reset method?